# Query & merge data from multiple JSON files

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to query and merge the contents of multiple JSON files. The goal is to open each file, load it into a JArray, and query the data with a JSONPath. Then take queryResults[n] and merge them into a single new JSON file. Below is a (hopefully clear) example.

File A (people):

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "GroupId": 5,
    "Name": {
      "First": "Tony",
      "Last": "Stark"
    },
    "Phone": "1111111111"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "GroupId": 5,
    "Name": {
      "First": "Steve",
      "Last": "Rogers"
    },
    "Phone": "2222222222"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "GroupId": 6,
    "Name": {
      "First": "John",
      "Last": "Doe"
    },
    "Phone": "3333333333"
  }
]
```

File B (groups):

```
[
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Description": "Avengers"
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "Description": "Others"
  }
]
```

File C (desired result):

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": {
      "Last": "Stark"
    },
    "GroupDescription": "Avengers"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": {
      "Last": "Rogers"
    },
    "GroupDescription": "Avengers"
  }
]
```

Ideally, I would like to do as much of this as possible with a JSONPath and JSON.NET (Newtonsoft). Assume File A & File B are both JArrays already. But I really don't know how to write a JSONPath expression like that to query each and then merge the results. Is it possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Linq`:

```
var peopleList = JArray.Parse(peopleJson);

var groupList = JArray.Parse(groupJson);

var expectedResult = peopleList.Select(s => new
{
    Id = s["Id"].ToString(),
    Name = new { First = s["Name"]["First"].ToString() },
    GroupDescription = groupList.FirstOrDefault(f => f["Id"].ToString() == s["GroupId"].ToString())["Description"].ToString()

}).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that would work if I knew the structures ahead of time. The reason I am trying to use JSONPath instead is that the document structures and the desired output are only known at runtime. I'm trying to generically pass in some parameters (like a JSONPath string and the paths to the JSON files) and then dynamically generate the results.

Comment: Without knowing the structures how would you merge items? If we are talking about the passing parameter, you can pass parameters to Linq as well like  `groupList.FirstOrDefault(f => f[parameter1].ToString() == s[parameter2].ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` has useful utilities for Json manipulation. You can build a JSON object or an Array using primitives like `JObject` and `JProperty`. This will save you from deserialization and re-serialization :

```
    var json1 = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 1,\r\n    \"GroupId\": 5,\r\n    \"Name\": {\r\n      \"First\": \"Tony\",\r\n      \"Last\": \"Stark\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"Phone\": \"1111111111\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 2,\r\n    \"GroupId\": 5,\r\n    \"Name\": {\r\n      \"First\": \"Steve\",\r\n      \"Last\": \"Rogers\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"Phone\": \"2222222222\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 3,\r\n    \"GroupId\": 6,\r\n    \"Name\": {\r\n      \"First\": \"John\",\r\n      \"Last\": \"Doe\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"Phone\": \"3333333333\"\r\n  }\r\n]";
    var json2 = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 5,\r\n    \"Description\": \"Avengers\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 6,\r\n    \"Description\": \"Others\"\r\n  }\r\n]";
    var mainArray = JArray.Parse(json1);
    var groupArray = JArray.Parse(json2);
    var targetArray = new JArray();
    foreach (JObject o in mainArray)
    {
        var id = o.Value<int>("GroupId");
        var target = groupArray.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Value<int>("Id") == id);
        if (target == null)
            continue;
        var newObj = new JObject();
        newObj["Id"] = id;
        var name = new JObject(new JProperty("Last",o["Name"]["Last"]));
        newObj["Name"] = name;
        newObj["GroupDescription"] = target["Description"];
        targetArray.Add(newObj);
    }
    var targetJson = targetArray.ToString();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EWuuo)

Comment: See the comment I made above to @selim-yildiz - also, performance is important, but not my primary concern right now. Generic functionality is more important for this.